# Multilevel, hierarchical, and structural equation (SEM) models

Tags: multilevel-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, hierarchical-bayesian

Are all three of these just terms for the same idea or are there some critical differences? If so, how do they differ both in usage and principle?

Comment: This is a huge topic. Very short answer is that multilevel and hierarchical typically refer to the same type of model (also referred to as mixed effects models). SEM is different, although it and the others can be subsumed into a generalized latent variable modeling framework. Some of the best thinking and exposition on the connections among these is by Sophia Rabe-Hesketh and Anders Skrondal. See http://www.gllamm.org/sophia.html#gllamm for software and references. Their 2004 book is particularly good. Also, see Mplus software - https://www.statmodel.com/.

Comment: Different people mean totally different things by hierarchical regression. But multilevel models which analyzes variables clustered inside other variables is very different than SEM which analyzes latent factors through observed data. When I studied them they did not seem to have much in common.

Comment: They have a lot in common, actually. The biggest thing is that they both model latent (hidden/unobserved) variables that account for the correlation between items (SEM) and for correlations between repeated observations of the same variable (multilevel/mixed effects models). In SEM, we call these factors and in MLM we call them random intercepts. At a high level, it is the same idea.